# Docker container fails to connect to psql. psql: could not connect to server. docker compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, psql

I need to import the schema into the db in the container and, I already had this whole thing going, imported the db schema, made sure the app is up and running and made a commit and had started working on the other aspects of the app. When I later tried to build the image `docker compose up --build` got this error:

`psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory the server running locally and accepting`

tried to figure this out a little, then just gave up and reset to the latest commit when it still worked... the issue persisted...

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    tty: true
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: fusionsolar
      POSTGRES_USER: fusionsolar
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: fusionsolar
    ports: 
      - "5432:5432"
    extra_hosts:
    - "db:127.0.0.1"

  web:
    tty: true
    image: ghcr.io/a-lehmann-elektro-ag/fusionsolar_webplugin
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./public:/mnt/public
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
      POSTGRES_DB: fusionsolar
      POSTGRES_USER: fusionsolar
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: fusionsolar
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client systemctl
WORKDIR /myapp

COPY . /myapp/

RUN bundle install


# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts.
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000

# Configure the main process to run when running the image
CMD ./start-dev.sh
```

`start-dev.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

DATABASE_NAME="fusionsolar"
DB_DUMP_LOCATION="./schema.sql"

echo "*** CREATING DATABASE ***"
psql "$DATABASE_NAME" < "$DB_DUMP_LOCATION";
echo "*** DATABASE CREATED! ***"


rm /src/tmp/pids/server.pid
bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5

rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000
```

`entrypoint.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# Remove a potentially pre-existing server.pid for Rails.
rm -f /myapp/tmp/pids/server.pid

# Then exec the container's main process (what's set as CMD in the Dockerfile).
exec "$@"
```

I tried to delete all the images and `docker system prune -a`, but it didn't work. I also made sure that the db is actually running, logged into the container and it indeed was running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you just directly run `psql` like that, it looks for [a set of standard environment varibales](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html) like `$PGHOST` and `$PGUSER`, but absent those variables, it will try to connect to the database using a Unix socket.  Since you're in a separate Rails application container, that socket file won't exist.

The absolute easiest thing here to do will be to use the [Rails Active Record migration system](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html).  This will use the same database configuration you already have in your `config/database.yml` file.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# entrypoint.sh

# remove a stale pid file (if any)
rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid

# run database migrations (automatically on every container startup)
bundle exec db:migrate

# run the main container CMD, in a Bundler context
exec bundle exec "$@"
# (example: `CMD rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000`)
```

If you do need to use `psql` separately, your script can access the Compose `environment:` variables directly, and you'll need to pass those variables to `psql` options or the more standard `$PG*` environment variables.

```bash
PGPASSWORD="$POSTGRES_PASSWORD" \
psql \
  -h "$DB_HOST" \
  -d "$POSTGRES_DB" \
  -u "$POSTGRES_USER" \
  -f schema.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Your psql error comes from your `web` container, trying to resolve the DB_HOST of a `db` hostname for the other container. Instead of creating extra_hosts like that, i suggest you to use [docker compose bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#networks) instead.

So then the `web` container can resolve where the `db` host ip goes.

Here the updated docker compose file:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    tty: true
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: fusionsolar
      POSTGRES_USER: fusionsolar
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: fusionsolar
    ports: 
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - fusionsolar

  web:
    tty: true
    image: ghcr.io/a-lehmann-elektro-ag/fusionsolar_webplugin
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./public:/mnt/public
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
      POSTGRES_DB: fusionsolar
      POSTGRES_USER: fusionsolar
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: fusionsolar
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
    networks:
     - fusionsolar
volumes:
  dbdata:
networks:
    fusionsolar:
        driver: bridge
```